# MySQL to PHP double quote issue

Tags: php, mysql, special-characters, data-cleaning

I have a database that contains multiple film synopsis - which are blocks of text that were emailed to me and which I copy-pasted into my database.
I'm now trying to parse them back out with a simple PHP script - and I keep getting errors.
I'm suspecting its due to double-quotes, ampersands, and other special characters in the text blocks - so how do I clean this up?

Here's my code:

```
    $query = "select * from Films";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo "<film>";

            echo "<ID>";
              echo $row['ID'];
            echo "</ID>";

            echo "<FilmName>";
              echo $row['FilmTitle'];
            echo "</FilmName>";

            echo "<FilmGenre>";
              echo $row['FilmGenre'];
            echo "</FilmGenre>";   

            echo "<FilmSynopsis>";
              echo $row['FilmSynopsis'];
            echo "</FilmSynopsis>"; 

        echo "</film>";
    }
```

I'm pretty much always crashing at the SYNOPSIS part - cause that's what has the most amount of text and therefore the most occurrences of "problematic" characters.

Is there some way to clean this up on the fly?

Comment: "keep getting errors".  What errors do you get? "always crashing"  What do you mean by "crashing"?  What happens?

Comment: I get this:  `This page contains the following errors:
error on line 7 at column 3809: Encoding error
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.`  And the output is lots of unformatted text - meaning, not a nice XML document-tree.

Comment: You'll have to figure out what the error is before trying clean it up. Can you use another client to query MySQL and see what's up around the 3809th character of that row?

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient MySQL extension: it is no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should use either the improved [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) extension or the [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) abstraction layer.

Comment: Ah, sorry, but I have no idea what you are referring to with "ancient MySQL extension." Seriously. I'm an iOS developer - not a MySQL or PHP guy. The code I'm using I've cobbled together from various tutorials I found online - and its worked fairly well thus far. I didn't realize it was old or deprecated - what specifically is deprecated in it?

Comment: @Ansari - I tried the PHP script in both Firefox and Safari. FF shows a little more of the output - but all on one huge long line. The error is slightly different: `Line 7 Column 3831` in FF as opposed to `Line 7 Column 3809` in Safari. Weird.  I know that prior to my posting this, when I was manually cleaning up the text-paragraphs, the error kept "moving" to different parts of the doc. So as things were fixed, it found new problems further down the road...

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`htmlentities($str, ENT_DISALLOWED)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) to escape your content before echoing it into your XML:

```
$query = "select * from Films";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo "<film>";

        echo "<ID>";
          echo htmlentities($row['ID'], ENT_DISALLOWED);
        echo "</ID>";

        echo "<FilmName>";
          echo htmlentities($row['FilmTitle'], ENT_DISALLOWED);
        echo "</FilmName>";

        echo "<FilmGenre>";
          echo htmlentities($row['FilmGenre'], ENT_DISALLOWED);
        echo "</FilmGenre>";   

        echo "<FilmSynopsis>";
          echo htmlentities($row['FilmSynopsis'], ENT_DISALLOWED);
        echo "</FilmSynopsis>"; 

    echo "</film>";
}
```

Comment: No good - getting this: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO, expecting ')' in line 37`  -- where line 37 is the very first call of htmlentities...syntax error?

Comment: @sirab333: What version of PHP?

Comment: no, my bad - I mistyped.  So now I _am_ getting the XML tree - which is a big step forward - but I'm also getting lots of errors within it:  `<film>
<ID>
<br/>
<b>Warning</b>
: htmlentities() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in on line 37
<b>
`  etc.  It repeats this same error for line 41, 45, 49, 53, etc

Comment: No, this is my code: `echo "<ID>"; echo htmlentities($row['ID'], ENT_DISALLOWED); echo "</ID>"; echo "<FilmName>"; echo htmlentities($row['FilmTitle'], ENT_DISALLOWED); echo "</FilmName>";`   etc.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use some "third-party" to export the structure out rather than write something that generates XML?

Comment: @nrathaus: Define "better"?  If outputting HTML, would you output raw tags or use a third-party library?  Both have their pros and cons, depending on the circumstances.

Comment: Using something like libxml, would handle everything for you, you create the HASHed or ARRAYed structure, provide it with the value, ask it to return a string and vola, everything is done for you, encoding, escaping, etc

Answer (score 0):

try this:

`htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8')`